# ¿Cómo mostrar y centrar una JInternalFrame adentro de otra?

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

Tengo un `JFrame` (ventana) y en este coloqué un panel y una barra de menú, mediante un `menuItem` que tiene un evento de `actionPerformed` abro una `JInternal Frame` y  mediante otra función la centro, solo que tengo un inconveniente al instante de que se presenta la ventana interna que se llama al final.

Hasta el momento lo que se me muestra por pantalla serían los elementos que contiene la última ventana (no se muestra la ventana, es decir, el recuadro donde está el panel y los otros elementos como etiquetas, botones entre otros).

En la ventana principal (llamada SISconfig) tengo una barra de menú que a su vez tiene varios items de menú y en uno de ellos mediante un evento muestra la ventana interna (vnaGestUsu), en esta ventana se va a encontrar un botón que va a abrir otra ventana interna; muestro el código que se encuentra en esta interfaz:

```
public class SISconfig extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    FuncVentanas vnaFunc = new FuncVentanas();
    vGestUsuarios vnaGestUsu = new vGestUsuarios();
    
    public SISconfig() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pnlEscritorio.add(vnaGestUsu);
    }

    private void usuariosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        vnaGestUsu.setVisible(true);
        vnaFunc.CentrarVentanaInterna(pnlEscritorio, vnaGestUsu);
    }
```

código de la otra internal frame (vnaGestUsu):

```
public class vGestUsuarios extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
    vCreaUsuario vnaCreaUsu = new vCreaUsuario();

    public vGestUsuarios() {
        initComponents();   
        pnlEscritorio.add(vnaCreaUsu);
    }
   
    private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        vnaCreaUsu.setLocationRelativeTo(this); //método inexistente
        vnaCreaUsu.toFront();
        vnaCreaUsu.setVisible(true);
    }
```

código de la clase donde se encuentra la función CentrarVentana:

```
public class FuncVentanas extends JFrame{
    public void CentrarVentanaInterna(JPanel panel, JInternalFrame subvna) {
        int x = (panel.getWidth() / 2) - (subvna.getWidth() / 2);
        int y = (panel.getHeight() / 2) - (subvna.getHeight() / 2);
        subvna.setLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```

En algunos sitios que estuve consultando, tienen que se puede centrar la ventana interna dentro de otra ventana interna mediante `ventanaInterna.setLocationRelativeTo(ventanaPadre)` no he logrado encontrar algún ejemplo sobre la utilización pero a mi criterio lo implemente como se indica el la acción del botón obviamente sin éxito ya que solo hay el método `setLocation` que recibe un punto o dos enteros que son las coordenadas.

**Alguien tiene alguna idea sobre el tema que me pueda enseñar?**

Comment: Hola Santiago, para que funcione **setLocationRelativeTo()** de declararse después del **setVisible(true)**, osea que quedaría así: **private void btnNuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        vnaCreaUsu.toFront();
        vnaCreaUsu.setVisible(true); vnaCreaUsu.setLocationRelativeTo(this);**

Comment: Ruslan hago esta pregunta por este medio ya que no encuentro algún sitio donde me indiquen sobre el tema, si te molesta la pregunta mil disculpas pero tu comentario da a entender que tienes una actitud negativa